# Internet speed / Skype Video calling

Tags: internet, skype, connection, download-speed

I have unlimited internet 512Kbps for 24 hours. If I want to make a video call on skype all night long or at least 9-10 hours. 512Kbps is enough to running a video call without lose connection?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the official Skype FAQ](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1417/how-much-bandwidth-does-skype-need), Skype has these bandwidth requirements for different types of calls:

```
Call type           Minimum down/upload speed   Recommended down/upload speed
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Calling             30kbps / 30kbps             100kbps / 100kbps

Video calling /
Screen sharing      128kbps / 128kbps           300kbps / 300kbps

Video calling
(high-quality)      400kbps / 400kbps           500kbps / 500kbps

Video calling
(HD)                1.2Mbps / 1.2Mbps           1.5Mbps / 1.5Mbps

Group video
(3 people)          512kbps / 128kbps           2Mbps / 512kbps

Group video
(5 people)          2Mbps / 128kbps             4Mbps / 512kbps

Group video
(7+ people)         4Mbps / 128kbps             8Mbps / 512kbps
```

So if you have 512 kbps *symmetric upstream and downstream*, you should be able to perform audio calls as well as normal and high quality video calls without problems. Even group video chats up to 3 people should be at least possible.

You pretty surely won't be able to perform HD video calls or group chats with more than 3 people though.

Comment: Lol, we posted the same thing 15 seconds apart :D